# NSDictionary to NSString not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsurlsession

I'm completely new to native iOS programming and have some small and big questions about it. One of my questions is the following:

I want to retrieve a `user_id` from a server, so I use `NSURLSession`. My code looks like that:

```
NSString *phone_nr = @"00436604056720";
__block NSString *user_id;

NSURLSession *session_json = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session_json dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/picshare/index.php?phone_nr=%@", phone_nr]] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
   NSLog(@"%@", json);

   user_id = @"%@",[json objectForKey:@"user_id"];
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

The code works fine (I retrieve the correct `user_id` and `phone_nr`) but I can't `alert` the `user_id`... but when I `NSLog` it, it works great. Problem is that I can't use the `user_id` variable anywhere outside of the function.

The `UIAlertView` looks like that:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Headline"
                                                    message:user_id
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: i hope you have invoked [alert show]?

Comment: From the documentation: `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` creates an HTTP GET request for the specified URL, then calls a handler **upon completion.**

Comment: user_id = @"%@",[json objectForKey:@"user_id"]; is a "comma expression". Look up in your beginner's C book what a comma expression is. I bet you didn't want to use one here.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *phone_nr = @"00436604056720";

NSURLSession *session_json = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session_json dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/picshare/index.php?phone_nr=%@", phone_nr]] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
   NSLog(@"%@", json);

   NSString *user_id = [json objectForKey:@"user_id"];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Headline"
                                                message:user_id
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
  });
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

Do not declare the _block variable.

Comment: The "release" version should of course check the HTTP status code and the MIME type of the response *before* feeding the parser with (possible) HTML which is sent from the server in case of a problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Items:

- I'm not sure I, or the compiler, parse this line:

  ```
    user_id = @"%@",[json objectForKey:@"user_id"];
  ```
- `user_id` will only be set *after* the block is called, which will not be "in line" to the code. How/when do you kick off your alert?
- `user_id` also risks autorelease. Is the object valid when you hit your alert?

---

#### Addendum

Responding to [@CouchDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465677/couchdeveloper)'s comment, given

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"compiler": @"Apple LLVM 5.1"};
NSString *s = @"%@", [d objectForKey:@"compiler"];
```

My compiler yields

```
<path elided>: error: expected identifier or '('
NSString *s = @"%@", [d objectForKey:@"compiler"];
                     ^
<path elided>: error: missing '[' at start of message send expression
NSString *s = @"%@", [d objectForKey:@"compiler"];
                      ^
                      [
<path elided>: error: expected ']'
NSString *s = @"%@", [d objectForKey:@"compiler"];
                                                 ^
<path elided>: note: to match this '['
NSString *s = @"%@", [d objectForKey:@"compiler"];
                     ^
3 errors generated.
```

Your compiler may differ.

Comment: The compiler _will_ parse this without an error. Please look up the "comma operator". It's likely a typo in the OPs code, though. _user_id_ will be set _during_ the block executes. Actually, the __block variable will live on the heap when this happens. It also doesn't matter whether the returned object from accessing the array is autoreleased or not.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Please look up. My response above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. I think you are not using `[alert show];`

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Headline"
                                                    message:user_id
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got Your solution->

**First for->** "Problem is that I can't use the user_id variable anywhere outside of the function"

**Solution->** use NSUserDefault to save the user id from block, or you can use a property variable to store user_id

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"USER_ID"];
```

Or

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *user_id;
```

**Second for->** "but I can't alert the user_id..."

**Solution->** Do this inside your block to call UIAlert View

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertWithTitle:)
                           withObject:user_id
                        waitUntilDone:YES];

- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)t
{
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:t
                                 message:nil
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil
    ] autorelease] show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use `UIAlertView` to display the user ID to the user.  However, I don't think that's your main problem here.  I don't believe you have a full grasp of your variable scope or c-blocks.  Let's take a look at a simple example:

```
__block NSString *myID = nil;
[someObject getMyID:^(NSString *returnedID){
    myID = returnedID;
    NSLog(@"%@", myID); //myID has a value here
}];

NSLog(@"%@", myID); //myID is "NULL" here
```

So what is happening here is you're passing to `someObject` a block of code it can use to return `returnedID` once it has acquired it.  This is normally done asynchronously, which means the method/function that called `getMYID` doesn't wait for the value.  The rest of the statements in the method are processed *before* `someObject` can return `returnedID` and pass it to the block you gave it. This means that `myID` will be set until long after the method that created it has finished. Because `myID` was created inside the function, it's scope is done when that method has finished. However, `myID` will stick around because the block you passed to `someObject` is keeping a reference to it. Once that block is executed, `myID` is destroyed and the value is lost.

Likely, what you want is an instance variable that can stick around after the method has returned.  So for example, you may have a property:

```
@property (strong) NSString *myID;
```

and now in your implementation you can do:

```
[someObject getMyID:^(NSString *returnedID){
    self.myID = returnedID;
}];
```

Now the value that `someObject` returns will stick around because it is assigned to an instance variable who's scope will last so long as the object that called `getMyID` lasts. Just be aware that it won't actually be set until a bit later (whenever `someObject` gets around to calling the block you passed it).

If you only need the value to stick around only for the method call, you'll probably just need to put that code in the block you pass to `someObject getMyID`:

```
[someObject getMyID:^(NSString *returnedID){
    //Do stuff with returnedID;
}];
```

Others have mentioned `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //do stuff });`. The reason for this is that likely the block of code you passed to `someObject` won't be called on the main thread, and any code that accesses the UI (like `UIAlertView`) must be called on the main thread.  `dispatch_async` will allow you to do this.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i created `user_id` property and returned the id to it, but i can't access that variable **outside** of the function. i actually want to assign it in the function and after that i want to use it somewhere else. i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Any variable you create inside a function *can never* be used outside of the function.  It will be destroyed when the function completes. You have to create a variable outside the function you can access (like an instance variable). Any block you pass to another function (ex: `[object doBlock:^(parameters, ...){ //code }]`) will be performed **outside** the function it was called from. The function *can* (but doesn't have to) run the block asynchronously, which means that block of code will be run some time **after** the function that called it has completed.

Comment: @JohnBrunner You seem to be missing some fundamental knowledge of how variables, scope, blocks and objective-c in general work.  Here's a good tutorial on c "blocks": [Blocks Tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/programming-with-blocks-an-overview/). Also, here's a general tutorial on Objective c: [Objective-c Tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/beginners-ios-development-objective-c/). You can use these to get an overall understanding of objective-c works with variables, scope and blocks.